# Inserting pdf/images in postgresql bytea column in php

Tags: php, postgresql, pdf, pdo

I'm trying to insert pdf or image as blob in postgresql bytea column. Here's what I tried

```
$file =  $_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][$i];
        if($file != '') {
            $p = fopen($file,'r');
            $data = fread($p,filesize($file));
            $data = addslashes($data);
//                $data = file_get_contents($file);
            $escaped_data = pg_escape_bytea($data);
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['attachments']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $blobQuery = $dbconn->prepare("INSERT INTO app_blob(blob_name, blob_type, blob_date, blob_data) values(:blob_name,:blob_type,NOW(),:blob_data) RETURNING blob_id");
            $blobQuery->bindParam(':blob_data', $escaped_data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            $blobQuery->bindParam(':blob_name', $_FILES['attachments']['name'][$i]);
            $blobQuery->bindParam(':blob_type', $ext);
            $blobQuery->execute();
            $blob_id = $blobQuery->fetchColumn();
        }
```

I tried in many different ways too, like without specifying the parameter type. I either get an empty white pdf or a corrupted one. What is the best way to achieve what I want here?

Comment: Use PDO, and do *not* use `pg_escape_bytea` or `pg_unescape_bytea`. Just pass `PDO::PARAM_LOB`.

Comment: Thanks Craig, your comment helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out what I was doing wrong. I'm posting the updated code here if someone gets into a similar problem later and need help like me. As Craig mentioned we don't have to use `pg_escape_bytea` or `addslashes`. All we need is to simply open the file using fopen and in my case in binary format and the bind the parameter specifying the parameter type as `PDO::PARAM_LOB`.

```
  $file =  $_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][$i];
        if($file != '') {
            $p = fopen($file,'rb');
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['attachments']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $blobQuery = $dbconn->prepare("INSERT INTO app_blob(blob_name, blob_type, blob_date, blob_data) values(:blob_name,:blob_type,NOW(),:blob_data) RETURNING blob_id");
            $blobQuery->bindParam(':blob_data', $p, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            $blobQuery->bindParam(':blob_name', $_FILES['attachments']['name'][$i]);
            $blobQuery->bindParam(':blob_type', $ext);
            $blobQuery->execute();
            $blob_id = $blobQuery->fetchColumn();
            $mime_type = $_FILES['attachments']['type'][$i];
            $attachmentQuery = $dbconn->prepare("INSERT INTO msg.email_attachment(email_id,blob_id,mime_type,is_in_line) values($email_id,$blob_id,:mime_type,1)");
            $attachmentQuery->execute(array(
                ':mime_type' => $mime_type
            ));
        }
```

[this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) may come to help from where I got into the solution.